# Subgroup Test Example

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a group, and $h$ an element of $G$. Prove that $\{g \in G : gh = hg\}$
is a subgroup of $G$.

Any sort of explanation is appreciated. I don't have a solution since I'm not sure how to start this. Tried reading up on subgroup tests but I feel an example is needed.

Comment: To be on the safe side your example is not a subgroup

Comment: By the [two step subgroup test](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Two-Step_Subgroup_Test), we only need to show $e$ is in the set, the set is closed under multiplication and the set is closed under taking inverse. $e$ being in the set is clear since $e h = h = h e$. Now take any $x, y$ in the set, $x y h = x h y = h x y$, so $x y$ is in the set as well. Next, take any $x$ in the set, $x h = h x \implies h = x^{-1} h x \implies h x^{-1} = x^{-1} h$, so $x^{-1}$ is in the set too. We are done.

Comment: This has been answered before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1670092/the-center-of-a-group-is-an-abelian-subgroup)

Comment: @BBC, that question is about the center, this question is about the centralizer.

Comment: @flo, the way I read the question, it's not about elements that commute with everything, it's about elements that commute with one particular element, $h$.

Comment: @Alex, why is a test with three steps called the two-step test?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I guess that's because checking nonemptyness is easy and is often omitted...